# How to mock a dictionary?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, rhino-mocks

First, I'd better ask if I should mock dictionaries? And if I should how can I achieve that?

I am using Rhino Mocks. I looked through its documentation and saw that it can mock ArrayList. So I tried it on Dictionary but no luck. I got the error that I'm not calling a virtual method bla bla... Will it be a problem if I don't mock it?

Answer (score 3):

You can only mock interfaces, or classes with virtual methods: you can't mock a `Dictionary<K,V>`, but you can mock an `IDictionary<K,V>`.

It depends on your situation, but it might be enough to construct a real dictionary, and fill it with mock objects.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your specific test scenario I wouldn't mock a .NET framework class, because you can take it as given that they work correctly.

Exceptions to this rule may apply to classes that give access to external ressources (like File or SQLConnection) but this is because you don't want to setup these ressources in your unit test, not because you don't want to test the classes themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I can assure you that the Dictionary works fine in .Net :)

I think you need to be pragmatic when writing your tests and not try to mock everything. Because how far can you go? How would you mock an int? Obviously it is discussable where is the border line, but I usually don't mock:

- .Net framework as long as it doesn't connect to some external resources
- my own trivial classes (i.e. ones that only store data)
- static helper methods (these should be really simple though), including extension methods